# Prevent HTML5-video in flex-container from overflowing in all browsers

Tags: css, html, flexbox, html5-video

I'm working on a dialog that allows the user to take pictures via webcam and/or add image files from the computer and upload those to a server. There's a preview of the webcam image and some buttons inside a flexible (flex) container. I've been using the following snippet:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <video src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer with buttons and stuff</div>
</div>
```

This is working great in Chromium and Chrome browsers, but in Firefox in the Edge browser the video-element is overflowing, pushing the buttons out of the container, leveraging the dialog unusable. Is there any way to get this done for all browsers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how big should the video be? should it be the same size as the .wrapper?

Comment: yes, that would be perfect, but the size should not be hardcoded in case i need to add other elements

Comment: That video element is one tough cookie (and stubborn as hell!). It just doesn't want to shrink. The only thing that worked for me was making the video's parent (`.content`) also a flex container. But then you have a width issue. https://jsfiddle.net/18w1d4c7/3/

Comment: Okay nice, I think I got it, check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/s5p2hub6/

Comment: I thought you wanted the wrappers to shrink-to-fit the video content. If you don't care that the wrappers get the full width of the window, and the video width is shorter than its containers, then this problem becomes much easier and has several solutions.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I guess the information I provided in my question have not been precise enough then. Is there any better solution than the one we got here now?

Comment: Flexbox is not very good with max-height

Comment: Please elaborate.